# One act of theft, from multiple victims

Tags: halacha, money, gezel-stealing

If someone commits some sort of theft of e.g. tax money, such as lying in order to get benefits they don't qualify for, or a government worker stealing from the office, or embezzlement... **is that one sin because it is one act, or millions of individual sins of theft; one for every tax payer?**

[Halachipedia claims](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Being_Careful_With_Other_People%27s_Money#Stealing_from_an_Institution), based on "Halachos of Other People's Money" p 31, that a collective like an institution is considered the property of the individual owners rather than a distinct entity, and also clarifies that if the amount stolen divided by the number of the group is less than a pruta, it is still considered stealing. These are relevant points but I would like to know the details, and try to get a proper answer to the main question in bold above.

Comment: There is only one *maasah gezeilah*.

Comment: It's not a given that it's halachic theft at all. See [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2010/07/cheating-the-government/) and [here](https://torah.org/learning/integrity-taxevasion/).